# Does use of cermet pots lead to scratching in a DC audio circuit?

Tags: audio, potentiometer

I am putting together an audio EQ module that is DC coupled.  I have read in many places that carbon pots will scratch due to DC present in the circuit.  Do cermet pots exhibit the same behavior?  I ask because I am able to find cermet pots that fit the PCB footprint, but not conductive plastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adjusting the pot causes a jump in the DC level of the circuit, you'll hear it as scratches, whooshes, or something. You could even use photocells with no mechanical parts whatsoever and still get adjustment noise.

To avoid this problem, don't put a DC *potential* across pots that touch the audio path.